# Here maps JS API — disable panning while scrolling on mobile

Tags: here-api

I have a map on my web page. When i scroll a page on the mobile device with one finger i want to prevent a map from panning.

Basically, i want Here maps to behave like Google or Yandex maps on mobile devices — by default map panning is available only with two fingers on mobile devices. One finger panning just do nothing and just scrolls the page not moves the map.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve something like this by disabling the Dragging behavior of the map.

```
 // boolean to check if map will receive events
    var mapEventsOn = false;

    // to move the page by the amount which was captured by the map canvas 
    map.addEventListener('pointerleave', 
        function(e) 
            { 
                eventEndY = e.currentPointer.viewportY;
                mapEventsOn = false;
                if(!behavior.isEnabled(H.mapevents.Behavior.DRAGGING)){
                    if(eventEndY > eventStartY){
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            window.scrollBy(0,-(eventEndY-eventStartY));
                          }, 0);
                    }else{
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            window.scrollBy(0,(eventStartY-eventEndY));
                          }, 0);


                    }
                }

            }
        );

    // to capture the pixel points from the drag/scroll action on map canvas    
    map.addEventListener('pointerdown', 
            function(e) 
            { 
                eventStartY = e.currentPointer.viewportY;
            }
    );

    // detect the scroll points from map events 
    map.addEventListener('pointerup', 
            function(e) 
            { 
                eventEndY = e.currentPointer.viewportY;
            }
    );


    map.addEventListener('pointercancel', 
            function(e) 
            { 
                mapEventsOn = false;
            }
    );

    map.addEventListener('pointerenter', 
            function(e) 
            { 
                mapEventsOn = true;
            }
    );    

document.addEventListener('touchmove', 
                function(e) 
                {
                    if(mapEventsOn)
                    {
                        var touch = e.touches[0];

                        if(e.touches.length == 1)
                        {
                            behavior.disable(H.mapevents.Behavior.DRAGGING);
                        }

                        if(e.touches.length == 2)
                        {
                            // This means there are two finger move gesture on screen
                            behavior.enable(H.mapevents.Behavior.DRAGGING);
                        }
                    }
                }, 
    false);
```

Comment: This is a total overkill.